# c# Multi Threading Processing large amount of data fast

Tags: c#, multithreading, text

Hey there i have like +15000000 record on a text file
and i need to process each line of them
is using multi threading will be useful
any suggestions ?
like for example creating 10000 thread and dividing 15000000 / 10000 to give each thread small ammount of data ?

Comment: Why don't just try and see - will it be any benefit from multithreading or not? Anyway, 10000 threads looks too much unless you have processor with 1000 cores.

Comment: Have a look at parallel Linq (PLinq): `File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt").AsParallel()...`: compare parallel (i.e. `AsParallel()`) and sequential (comment `AsParallel()` out) versions

Comment: There's a limit for how much threads you can open.

Comment: I second the recommendation for PLinq in this situation. If that proves to be too simplistic, though, take a look at TPL (Task Parallel Library, the `Task` class primarily) rather than creating your own `Thread` objects, since it will intelligently create them as necessary and reuse, etc..

Comment: Don't use 10k threads this will lead to disaster. Use the number of cores of your processor or x2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with *Parallel Linq* (PLinq):

```
var result = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
  .AsParallel()
  //.AsOrdered() // if you want to preserve the order of file lines
  .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10) // let's try 10 threads
  .Select(line => ProcessLine(line)) // whatever
  ...
```

You can easy compare *parallel* version with *sequential* one: either comment out `.AsParallel()` and `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)` or add `.AsSequential()`

Comment: are you propose to speed up reading of file?

Comment: @tym32167: often, the file reading speed is a *limiting factor* (esp. in case when the file has been stored on *HDD*). We can try separating file reading and file processing (while next file's chunk is reading we can well process some prior lines). In the best case, the time required to read and process the file equals to the time required just to read the file.

Comment: that's not what you are trying here. According with your code, you are trying read each line from file in parallel (and Im not sure that it safe or faster that sequental). And then, you want to process each line separately. How much context swithces it raises?  But you dont know, how much time spends for process 1 line. From my point, if process 1 line is very fast, there should be only 2 threads, one for reading file and one for processing.

Comment: @tym32167: `File.ReadLines` uses *buffer* when reading lines (i.e. it reads, e.g., 8k of the file data and then split it into, say, 20 lines which are now in memory buffer https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,d989485a49fbbfd2, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a4ada5f765646068). The best degree of parallelism (`2` or `10` or `Environment.ProcessorCount`) is mootable question, since we don't know (you're quite right!) the time required for the single line. That's why I recommended PLinq: the degree is easy to specify.

Comment: I didnt get how the fact about buffer affects on concurrent access to File.ReadLines. I didnt found anything about concurrent access to File.ReadLined in MSDN. But still dont think that we can suggest anything to user without knowing about ProcessLine(...) function, because in case where ProcessLine is much faster than reading, its not make sense to use multithreading at all. If this ProcessLine is  veery slow, it makes sense to change this ProcessLine to be able process chunk of lines at once.

Comment: @tym32167: you're quite right: if `ProcessLine` is fast (e.g `line => line.Length`), there's no need in parallel processing at all: file reading speed is a limiting factor and we can't speed up HDD. However, *PLinq* makes *playing* with parallel processing easy (what if I allocate `10` threads? what if I force parallelism `.WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)`?). I do not recommend *PLinq* as a heal-all remedy, but as a means to *play with data* and decide whether it worth parallel processing or not.

Comment: ook, I wrote as answer my point without answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a thread safe collection and a parallel loop. Say you read all lines into a thread safe list, you can use it this way:

required Namespaces:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Code:

```
ConcurrentBag<string> items = new ConcurrentBag<string>(File.ReadLines(@"C:\input.txt"));
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
Parallel.ForEach<string>(items, po, line =>
{
    ProcessItem(line);
});
```

Comment: are you propose to read all data before starting processing?

Answer (score 0):

That's really depends of your line processing function.
For example, I generated file with 5000000 lines. Then I created 3 functions:

```
void Seq()
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fname))
    {
        Process(line);
    }
}

void Parallel1()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(fname), line=>Process(line));
}

void Parallel2()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fname))
    {
        list.Add(line);
        if (list.Count > 1000)
        {
            var local = list;
            list = new List<string>();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(()=>local.ForEach(x=>Process(x))));
        }
    }

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(()=>list.ForEach(x=>Process(x))));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Then I wanted to test them in that way:

```
void Main()
{   
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Seq();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Seq {sw.Elapsed}");


    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel1();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Parallel1 {sw.Elapsed}");


    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel2();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Parallel2 {sw.Elapsed}");
}
```

and my process function is very fast:

```
private void Process (string line)
{   
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

I got results:

```
Seq 00:00:00.9817211
Parallel1 00:00:01.0199068
Parallel2 00:00:00.6581931 <- fastest
```

BUT, if I make my function even faster

```
private void Process (string line)
{   
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
    }
}

Seq 00:00:00.6474700 <- fastest
Parallel1 00:00:00.9247764
Parallel2 00:00:00.6642463
```

BUT2

if I make function slower:

```
private void Process (string line)
{   
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
    }
}

Seq 00:00:04.3995186
Parallel1 00:00:01.4569537 <- fastest
Parallel2 00:00:02.0348749
```

So, there are no correct answer, which faster, It depends at least of `Process` function and Im sure that it can depends of other stuff, like parallelism settings.